# Fedora 16 is not retrieving the mirror list

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

I have Fedora 16 installed. It gives me some errors/warnings when updating, and installing software through yum.

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-16&arch=x86_64 
error was 14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found: http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-16&arch=x86_64
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free
```

Answer (score 1):

Some backend servers have been migrated recently. If I recall correctly there has been a temporary outage.

Please try `yum clean all` then try again.

Comment: did yum clean all......but still no solution.giving error.... Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-16&arch=x86_64 error was
14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-16&arch=x86_64
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before. Just uninstall / install the rpmfusion repo.

```
sudo yum remove rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release
```

Then

```
sudo yum install rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release
```

Comment: This can generally be combined into a single step: `yum reinstall <packages>`